# ssh -T git@github.com reports error could not create directory '/.ssh'

Tags: git, ssh

I setup ssh key pair in centos container using `ssh-keygen`. Uploaded the public ssh key to my github account.

I run `ssh -T git@github.com` to check that i am connecting to the correct server and it errors out

```
$ ssh -T git@github.com                      
Could not create directory '/.ssh'.
```

Adding more information of my container environment

```
$ cat /etc/redhat-release 
CentOS Linux release 7.9.2009 (Core)
```

```
 
$ ls $HOME/.ssh/
id_rsa id_rsa.pub config
```

```
$ echo $HOME
/alabama

$ cat /alabama/.ssh/config                   
Host github.com                              
    StrictHostKeyChecking no                    
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Any thought what is causing the issue ? And how to fix it. Thanks

Comment: Key word: *container*. What is the setup *inside the container*?

Comment: It looks like, when you run `ssh -T git@github.com`, ssh thunks your home directory is `/`. You should debug further why this happens : for example run `whoami && echo $HOME && ssh -T github.com`, give more details on what you do prior to running `ssh -T github.com` (ssh into a container ? docker run ? ... ? ), etc ...